# Ajax jquery exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a very basic problem related to ajax jquery , need some guidance

```
$.ajax({
   type:"get",
   url:"www.google.com",
   success: function(html) {
    alert("success");
    },

    error : function(request,status,error) {
    alert(status);} //edited
 });
```

I am getting status as "error" , error variable as "".
I am not sure whats the problem . Check even with Verb "POST".

Edit : There was a typo in typing here. 
The syntax seems to be correct , even then the same error.

Here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1988/z7nnf0fh/

Comment: cross domain request?

Comment: Do you have a live demo?

Comment: The live demo does not give the same error. It says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)"

Comment: @Quentin: Could you please provide me with any proper sample url?

Comment: @user5283721 — I don't know what URL has the data you are trying to access.

Comment: @Quentin: This url has data right, why still I am getting error or my understanding is wrong?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: @user5283721 — What does the JavaScript console say? Presumably if the URL doesn't give you a 404 error, it gives you a different error. You need to read the error messages instead of just noticing the error function runs and then asking what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Your url is the problem for the `error`

```
 $.ajax({
 type:"get",
 url:"https://httpbin.org/", //Remove the url here..
 success: function(html) {
   alert("success");
},
error : function(request,status,error) {
  alert(status);} //edited
});
```

After removing this URL, got `success` in alert.
See on fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/smit_patel/0gety9oj/

Comment: It's depend what you want...?

Comment: Try this, It's a valid url

Comment: You can also change this URL with your original one.